# Validation on Xamarin forms is not displaying any error messages labels on Registration Form

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a registration page and their are entry fields that asks for first name, last name, email address and password to be filled in by the user. My RegistraionPage.xaml contains the error labels to be displayed, when the user leaves a field blank. I have AppResources file from which error labels are to be displayed. But it is not displaying any errors.

Here is the Registration.xaml,  view for FirstName to display the error labels when the FirstName entry field is left empty:

```
                <Entry.PlaceholderColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="{StaticResource DeviceBgColorSilver}" />
                </Entry.PlaceholderColor>
            </Entry>
            <Label x:Name="RegistrationPageViewModel_FirstNameError" IsVisible="False" TextColor="Red" />
```

Here is the RegistrationPageViewModel code for FirstName:

```
 public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

       [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AppResources))]
      [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Messages_FirstNameIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.AppResources))]
```

Here is the DoRegister command, that checks if the field is left empty:

```
  private async void DoRegister()
            { if (!ValidationHelper.IsFormValid(this, Application.Current.MainPage))
            {
                return;
            }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to show error message of on `Label` .You can use **`Validation Behaviour`**  to an Entry control:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter forename here" 
       Text="{Binding User.Forename, Mode=TwoWay}" 
       local:Validation.Errors="{Binding User.Errors[Forename]}" />
```

The Validation attached behavior gets and sets the Errors **BindableProperty**. The `User.Errors` property is provided by the ValidatableBase class, from which all model classes derive, and is an instance of the Validator class. The indexer of the Validator class returns a ReadOnlyCollection of error strings, to retrieve any validation errors for the Forename property.

```
public static class Validation
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ErrorsProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "Errors",
            typeof(ReadOnlyCollection<string>),
            typeof(Validation),
            Validator.EmptyErrorsCollection,
            propertyChanged: OnPropertyErrorsChanged);

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetErrors(BindableObject element)
    {
        return (ReadOnlyCollection<string>)element.GetValue(ErrorsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetErrors(BindableObject element, ReadOnlyCollection<string> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ErrorsProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnPropertyErrorsChanged(BindableObject element, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = element as View;
        if (view == null | oldValue == null || newValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var propertyErrors = (ReadOnlyCollection<string>)newValue;
        if (propertyErrors.Any())
        {
            view.Effects.Add(new BorderEffect());
        }
        else
        {
            var effectToRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is BorderEffect);
            if (effectToRemove != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Remove(effectToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the full code you can access the [sample](https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms/tree/master/Validation/MVVMUtopia/Views) on github.